# Count nested json objects from a nested array in python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file thats goes that way :

[image]

As you can see, for the category Chemistry, theres two blocks. In this JSON file, theres different categories, and I would like to count how many times there is "id's" inside a each category.

So for this example, I would like to have the sum of blocks found under "Chemistry".

This is what I did , but I received "TypeError:String indices must be integers"

```
import json


with open('prize.json') as jsonfile:

  nobel=json.load(jsonfile)
  prizes = nobel

  count = sum([len(item['prizes']['chemistry']) for item in nobel])
  print(count)
```

EDIT:

here is the JSON link:
http://api.nobelprize.org/v1/prize.json

And here the JSON viewer since it's very messy:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: I have a feeling `prizes` is an array and you're trying to access `chemistry` as if it were a dictionary. Can you please confirm / deny ?

Comment: `TypeError:String indices must be integers` is a common error when you're passing a non existent ( `None` or so value ) to get an element at an index in an array.
Please check `item['prizes']['chemistry']`

Comment: @ShyamPillai Yes I confirm. Prizes is the array, and I want to access Chemistry.

Comment: Can you post the dictionary as is, rather than an image ? That would help in debugging better.

Comment: @ShyamPillai I edited my question to add what you needed - thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ?

```
sum([len(item["laureates"]) for item in nobel["prizes"] if item["category"] is 'chemistry' and "laureates" in item])
```

`nobel` is basically the data you've read.

Comment: This works perfectly but had to change 'is' to '==' ! Thank you so much. Is there a way, to see the also all the other categories? For example 'Economics, Literature, peace, physics, medecine and economics? Or should I repeat this line of code for every category?

Comment: Do upvote or mark the above provided answer if the answer helps :) 
My 2 cents for the comment is that we have an empty array. We're anyways looping through the entire `nobel[prizes]` . So just have a `Set` add all the `category` values and by the end of the loop you'll have unique categories you need. Then we need to run the above. But I would say make the list of unique categories first and then have 1 single loop run through the data as opposed to running `n` number of times. Does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

first, you must known the structure of this json:
this json is an Object with a key "prizes",then the key "prizes" is an array, so if you want to get the content what you want,you must get the array from the "prizes" key

```
whatYouWillGet = [item for item in nobel]
print(whatYouWillGet)
// it will print ["prizes"]
```